# what opengl command uploads rambuffer to video texture

Tags: opengl, textures

Which command exactly uploads a ram pixel buffer into texture in video memory?

is this glTexImage2D(...) ? maybe or something other ?

If i got some texture and want to change ram buffer contents what commands can i use to re transfer it to video card?

What i could use for this purpose?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Essentially yes, glTexImage[1,2,3]D sets up a whole new OpenGL texture object and as a last step it also copies data into the texture. The data itself either comes from client memory (i.e. memory your program can access directly) or from a Pixel Buffer Object.

If you just want to alter the contents of a texture you should use glTexSubImage[1,2,3]D which only replaces the data, keeping the existing texture object.